# Amazon Athena: Dateparse shows Invalid Format

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have a CSV file having Orderdate as string in it. In Amazon Atena trying to use dateparse to convert the format of data but getting error. This is what i am trying:

```
select parse_datetime(orderdate,'%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s') from orders
```

> Error: INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "9/1/2015 15:43"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error on query parsing alb logs by datetime in aws athena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52146802/error-on-query-parsing-alb-logs-by-datetime-in-aws-athena)

Comment: For anyone who has multiple input formats, consider `coalesce(try(first approach), second_approach, ...)`. To be sure that everything is converted, don't use `try` in the last approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that your format string `'%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s'` does not match the orderdate string.

Your orderdate does not have seconds and the year is 4 digits. Change your format string to `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i'`

[Date and Time Functions and Operators](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html)

Comment: Updated my answer. I did not notice the 4 digit year issue.

Comment: ..Thankyou for the update but with this format it is throwing new error INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Illegal pattern component: i

Comment: My query worked by the string you gave '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i'. only change i made was intead of parse_datetime i used date_parse(orderdate,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i') and it worked like  a charm. Thankyou so much